# Bell puzzle in the Temple of Eothas

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

In the Temple of Eothas there are 3 bells that you have to ring to (presumably) open the door to the next level.

I've found one clue, that the large bell is to be rang second, where can I find the other clues (or what is the actual order).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The correct order is

> Right, Middle, Left, Right

Alternately, you can find a key in the same room where you found the clue that allows you to bypass the whole thing.

Comment: What are the requirements to find the key? I didn't and I had enough mechanics to find the two loot holes around the altars or whatever you want to call them.

Comment: I couldn't find it with 3, so more than that.

Comment: I found the key with 7 mechanics

Comment: Found it with 5 mechanics.

Comment: Man, I even found the note that was supposedly a hint and could not figure it out. In fact, it seemed to mislead.

Answer (score 14):

One of the clues came from a room to the far left and down (bottom of your screen). There is a small pool and a ghost I believe once you kill the Ghul or whatever was in there. I believe there is a note you loot from some container and tells the story or someone running and being late. (this may have come from a dream from the ghost in the room, I forget now). In the dream the person hears the bell, he refers to it as the right hand, and wonders if it was the first bell or the last. So now you know the Right bell is first and last.
   Sorry if I butchered the story, but that the room and that is at least the gist of what you learn there.

Comment: Do you know if there are any specific requirements to get that clue? I only had the OP's clue and figured out the answer through trial and error. Do you know which ghost and if it's repeatable?

Comment: I found the ghost (which tells you that the Right bell is first and last) and the note (which tells you that the Middle bell is second), but what tells me that the Left bell is third?

Answer (score 3):

I think it was like this:

1. Right bell
2. Middle bell
3. Left bell
4. Right bell

Answer (score 3):

In addition to these clues (the note found and the ghost dialogue), there is also a book in *the room with the books* that is described as being opened "often to a certain page" or something like that. It describes different gods speaking to a witness. Each bell symbolises a god. I solved the puzzle with this book and the tattered note. It's fun to know there were so many other solutions to such a simple puzzle! Awesome game. :)

Answer (score 1):

You only need the book of verses to solve the puzzle. Each God is a bell, and each time they speak in the story is the order that you ring the bell. Once you match the description of the bell sounds, to the description of the God’s voices, then you know the order of the bells. Also, the last God who speaks in the story is meant to confuse you, one God starts to speak but is interrupted.

Answer (score -3):

The correct order I found is Right, Middle, Left, Right